# What is wrong with this Grails BuildConfig?

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, grails-plugin

I am developing a Grails (2.3.6) app and plugin at the same time. I just finished writing my plugin's `BuildConfig.groovy` and it looks like:

```
grails.project.class.dir="target/classes"
grails.project.dependency.resolver="maven"
grails.project.repos.default="myrepo"
grails.project.test.class.dir="target/test-classes"

 grails {
    project {
        dependency {
            resolution {
                def gebVersion = "0.9.2"
                def seleniumVersion = "2.40.0"

                checksums = true
                dependencies {
                    compile 'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.107'
                    compile ('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.6') {
                        excludes 'groovy'
                    }
                    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'

                    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
                    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
                    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
                    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
                    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
                    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
                }
                inherits("global") {
                }
                legacyResolve = false
                log "error"
                plugins {
                    build ":release:3.0.1"
                    build ":tomcat:7.0.50.1"

                    compile "org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4"
                    compile ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3"
                    compile ":standalone:1.2.3"
                    compile ":cache-headers:1.0.4"
                    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
                    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
                    compile ":yammer-metrics:3.0.1-2"
                    compile ":webflow:2.0.8.1"
                    compile ":ajaxflow:0.2.4"

                    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
                    runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
                    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.8" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.1.1"
                    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
                    runtime ":jquery:1.11.0"

                    test(":geb:$gebVersion")
                    test(":spock:0.7") {
                        exclude "spock-grails-support"
                    }
                }
                repositories {
                    inherits true

                    grailsHome()
                    mavenLocal()
                    mavenRepo "http://myrepo01/myrepo/"
                    grailsPlugins()
                    grailsCentral()
                    mavenCentral()
                }
            }
        }

        fork = [
            test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
            run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
            war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
            console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
        ]

        repos {
            myrepo {
                url = "http://myrepo01/myrepo"
                type = "maven"
                username = "repouser"
                password = "12345"
            }
        }

        source {
            level = 1.7
        }

        target {
            level = 1.7
        }

        test {
            reports {
                dir = "target/test-reports"
            }
        }

        work {
            dir = "target/work"
        }
    }

    release {
        scm {
            enabled = false
        }
    }

    servlet {
        version = "3.0"
    }
}
```

When I run `grails run-app` from an app that imports this plugin, I get:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.6
| Error WARNING: Inline plugins for [myplugin] cannot be read due to error: No
signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.compile() is appl
icable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.mongodb.morphia:morph
ia:0.107]
Possible solutions: memoize() (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

How does Grails not understand the `compile` closure?!? I think there might be *something* going on with Grails not understanding the nested properties I've set up, but from what I can tell in the [Grails configuration guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html) I am using the nested property syntax correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: `resolution = { .. }`. Note `=`.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - but why do I need to add an "`=`" here, but not with, say, `plugins`? More importantly, how do I know (as a general rule) when to use "`=`" and when not to?

Comment: One is Closure assignment where `=` is used and another is closure as a parameter to a method call. If you look at the configuration guide again, `grails.project.dependency.resolution` is a closure.